# How to connect to facebook and use the invite module, so that users can invite there frieds from my website. jQuery or Php or facebook markup?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

In my website I have a invite option. Click and connect to Facebook for invite your friends, but they will be doing those in my website same page (ajax or iframe method for example).

But I don't find yet any working example which works with jQuery or PHP. Can someone guide me with an working link, which really does exactly how I am trying to implement.

Tried this but seems not working for me with jQuery and PHP ex: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Comment: Sorry I don't have it clear. What are trying to achieve, exactly? What do you need jquery and php for? FB has its set of XFBML for all the jobs, have a look at the devs page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: @Damien pirsy: I dont require all A to Z facebook features from this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ , All i need is the invite others module, which does not exist, or never works.

Comment: Ok, maybe I can't understand what do you need, but is something like this? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/

Comment: @Damien prisy: yes but thats not working with jQuery.

Comment: Thus you can either go for FBML way or try having a look here http://fbexchange.net/questions/193/facebook-invitation-form-inside-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: Is this good to use for Facebook then ? ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866598/how-to-connect-google-and-allow-my-user-to-invite-their-contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally this is the answer, to make life easy and peasy, hope it help others:

Step 1: copy and paste the following code -> change the appId with your own facebook developer id.

```
<p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
<!--    <p><fb:like></fb:like></p>-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({appId: '133500<--put your-->developerid', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {if (response.session) {FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', title:'Invite your friends to my cool site!', message: 'You have been invited to this cool site'});} else {}}); };(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Step 2: click  the facebook icon, login, and invite others, with your own letter?